# Automatically reconnect a Python Tornado Websocket Client Connection

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I am using Python Tornado's websocket_connect function ( http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/websocket.html ) to listen to a websocket feed.

Sometimes the websocket server will die, or disconnect the client (this is detectable ) and I need to figure out a way to clean up the old connection and reconnect the client. I could of course just restart the program but what is the proper way to do this through tornado?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing automatic for this. When it disconnects, just call `websocket_connect()` again.